# How to redirect old dynamic url to new dynamic url in CodeIgniter(HMVC)

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

I want to redirect my old dynamic URLs to new dynamic URLs as follows :

Old URL: http://girisite.com/travel_operators/operator/svr-tours-travels-online-booking

New URL: http://girisite.com/travel-operators/details/svr-tours-travels-online-booking

Please help with this?

Actually i am using like this:

RedirectMatch 301 ^/svr-tours-travels-online-booking/[^/]+/(.+)$ /travel-operators/details/$1

Redirection is working fine but after redirect, some unwanted text again adding like this:

http://girisite.com/travel-operators/details/svr-tours-travels-online-booking?/travel_operators/operator/svr-tours-travels-online-booking

which means->at the end ?along with old link segments added here. How to remove this?

Comment: How many others do you have? You can use routes to achieve this.

Comment: Are these URLs internal in your code or are they "outside in the wild links"? If they are just internal you could simply replace them. We don't yet know the full story so these are just things to consider for your case.

Comment: _“Please help with this?”_ - please explain what exactly you are having trouble with then. Please go read [ask]; this is not a code-writing service - you are supposed to show some initial effort here.